# helm install fails with - and _ in values

Tags: kubernetes-helm

```
helm install --name testapp ./testapp
Error: release testapp failed: ReplicationController "registry-creds-via-helm" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[0].valueFrom.secretKeyRef.name: Invalid value: "": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
```

Can anyone point out what is the problem with my below yaml?

```
# cat testapp/templates/replicationController-ngn.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: registry-creds-via-helm
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    version: v1.6
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: registry-creds-via-helm
    version: v1.9
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: registry-creds-via-helm
        version: v1.9
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: upmcenterprises/registry-creds:1.9
        name: registry-creds
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: registry-creds
                key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          - name: awsaccount
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: registry-creds
                key: aws-account
          - name: awsregion
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: registry-creds
                key: aws-region
          - name: aws-assume-role
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: registry-creds
                key: aws_assume_role
```

Comment: Your setting for AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID is missing a “name”.

Comment: that is right. thanks!